# In Batman v Superman, why can Lois see Gotham City from Metropolis?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Lois asks for a ’copter to take her to Gotham City.

Why is Gotham so close to Metropolis? It seems like a Newark-to-NYC proximity.

Comment: Because... that’s where they built it?

Comment: [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99799/5184) to the old question addresses this specifically.

Answer (score 2):

#### In Dawn of Justice at least, they are neighboring cities

[Zack Snyder Turned Gotham City and Metropolis Into the Bay Area:](http://www.wired.com/2015/07/dawn-of-justice-gotham-metropolis/)

> “The big rule that we broke is that we put Gotham and Metropolis right next to each other,” Snyder says. “It made sense to us and worked for our story that they were kind of sister cities across a big bay. It’s like Oakland and San Francisco, kind of.”

---

Although, from one arc to the next, the proximity of one city to the other changes to suit the story.

There really is no single answer to the question: *How far is Gotham from Metropolis?*, it's constantly changing.